# MySQL - find a value between

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 fields in the database - from and to. Both contains numbers. There are many records in the table with different ranges. How can I find in a query which range is that with a given number. For example, if I have a number 2005, I want to find that row where this number is between from and to. Thanks.

Comment: SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE from = '2005' or to = '2005' (if 2005 is string, if number remove the '

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: As a rule, avoid keywords (reserved or otherwise) in table/column identifiers. In time they will drive you bonkers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try with:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE `from` <= 2005
   AND `to` >= 2005
```

Nota: Both "from" and "to" are [MySQL reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) which must be wrapped in backticks.

Comment: "from" and "to" are both [MySQL reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and require *special attention* ;) it should be noted in your answer and handled accordingly/respectively. As it stands, this will throw an SQL error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sure thing - it's a pseudocode. OP didn't provide any info about columns.

Comment: OP states it in the question: *"I have 2 fields in the database - from and to"*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Better ? ;-)